# For loop function after event fails

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop, events

I have a for loop inside a declared function and it just seems to work for a milisecond (after being called in an event), then it goes right back at the begining. My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function nextImage() {

        var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

           var imageArray = images.length;

           var i;

           for (i = 0; i <= imageArray; i++) {

           images[i].removeAttribute('class');

           }

      }

       var nextButton = document.getElementById('next');

       nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextImage, false);

   </script>
```

I want the attribute of the images to be permanently removed after the event is performed. What am I missing?

Thank you very much.

Comment: One thing off the bat is the loop should be `i < imageArray` (the length will always be one greater than the last element index, since element index starts at 0).

Comment: ...and `imageArray` is a very strange name for a variable containing the length of an HTMLCollection.

Comment: Yeah, usually I don't give this sort of thing a unique name unless there's a compelling reason.  `i < images.length` would suffice.

Comment: *"...and it just seems to work for a milisecond, then it goes right back at the begining..."* It sounds like your `id="next"` element is a `button` element in a `form`, e.g. `<button id="next">Next</button>`. The (surprising) default `type` of `button` elements is `"submit"`, meaning that clicking the button submits the form. If the form's action is not given or is the page's own URL, that refreshes the page. Or of course, the `id="next"` is an `input type="submit"`.

Comment: Other than going one element too far, that should successfully remove all classes from your `img` elements (before throwing an error when you try to use `removeAttribute` on the non-existant last element). Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). We need more information to help you.

Comment: T.J. Crowder my issue was that the element with id "next" was a link <a> with an empty 'href'. After changing that to a 'button', my problem was successfully resolved. I could figure that out thanks to your first answer. Thank you very much.